# switch statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

Is the following switch statement correct? I mean can i use constant and character literal in one switch case statement?
It works in code but I am asking from good practices standpoint.

```
switch(arg[1]) {
    case '4':
        printf("value is 4\n");
        break;
    case '6':
        printf("value is 6\n");
        break;
    case 'M':
        printf("value is M\n");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: or, you know, `printf("value is %c\n", arg[1])`

Comment: A single character literal is a number, not something like "a very very short string".

Comment: That's syntactically legal, but `deafult:` is an ordinary label (that can be used as the target of a `goto`), not a `default:` label you'd normally use in a `switch` statement.

Comment: i wonder if these kinda questions are posted just to get upvotes..

Comment: Other than the misspelling of `default`, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @ralph You mean just to get downvotes, right?

Comment: @tom. well, you don't always get what you want..

Comment: corrected the spelling of default. my question is for case '4' and case 'M'. Can i have these both in a single switch?

Comment: @user1060517 sure, why not?

Comment: While taking variable as inputs just, I suggest you use fgets, rather than using scanf, rest is fine.

Comment: `'4'` and `'M'` are both character constants; neither is a variable. Your code doesn't illustrate the question you're trying to ask. The expression following the `case` keyword must be a constant expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It works in code but I am asking from good practices standpoint.

Yes, it's fine to use `char` variables and constants in `switch` statements. It's very common to see that, for example, [to process command line arguments](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-command-line-parameter-parsing). `char` is an integer type, and `switch` works as well with `char` as with any other integer type.